# Создание приложения с регистрацией и входом в аккаунт

Tags: java, android, авторизация, аутентификация

Я - начинающий Java-разработчик, и я уже работал с Android Studio. Недавно у меня появилась возможность единолично поучаствовать в разработке Android - приложения, но основная проблема для меня - реализация возможности регистрации в приложении. У меня есть идея: реализовать это через базу данных. То есть арендовать сервер и поставить на нем базу данных, после чего через JBDC отправлять на него запросы при входе в аккаунт, или регистрации аккаунта. Правильно ли я мыслю? Повторюсь - я новичек.

Comment: Да, если без всяческих тонкостей.

Comment: Я нашел выход лучше - Firebase от Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно, но следует сделать лучше.
Обращаться из приложения на смартфоне сразу в БД на сервере - не самая лучшая идея, не безопасно как минимум.

По хорошему бы на сервере ставите БД и пишете небольшой REST сервис, у которого между приложением на смартфоне и самим сервисом будет общение через, например, ключ авторизации.

То есть, этот сервис должен уметь авторизовывать HTTP запросы от приложения на смартфоне.

Сам запрос на сервер должен содержать:

1. Учетные данные для авторизации приложения
2. Учетные данные пользователя в зашифрованном виде

Сервер должен авторизовать приложение по ключу и проверять в БД такого пользователя с таким паролем. Если все ок, то говорить приложению, что такой юзер есть и он может быть авторизован.

Такой сервис можно собрать на коленке на Spring Security.

Это самая простая реализация. Она тоже не до конца безопасна, но для начала, думаю, пойдет.

Уверен, товарищи предложат лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase от Google - выход из этой ситуации. К тому же там есть база данных и еще много всяких полезностей.